# Understating DynamoDb Throughput

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

According  DynamoDb documentation : write/read throughput means ,dynamo db can support up to defined value per second ,but is this limit per partition or across the table :

For ex : In my Test table ,partition key is CustomerId ,lets say we have 5 different customers and write throughput is 200 ,does it mean dynamodb will support 200 writes per second for all 5 customers or 200 writes per second for each individual customer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question-** DynamoDB can support up to defined value per second, but is this limit per partition or across the table?

**Answer:** The throughput Limit is across the Table.

**Question-** For ex: In my Test table, partition key is CustomerId, lets say we have 5 different customers and write throughput is 200, does it mean dynamo DB will support 200 writes per second for all 5 customers or 200 writes per second for each individual customer?

**Answer:** Dynamo DB will support 200 writes per second for all 5 customers

AWS DynamoDB Documentation: [DynamoDb](http://AWS%20DynamoDB%20Documentation:%20DynamoDb)

[Some DynamoDB Slides](https://www.slideshare.net/AmazonWebServices/building-applications-with-dynamodb)

Comment: Thanks ASH , Can you please direct me to this source of information ,I could not find it anywhere .